# Return indices of non-NaN uniques in np.array of dtype=object

Tags: python, list, numpy, unique, nan

How do I return a list of indices corresponding to uniques in a `np.array` of `dtype=object`?

Analogous to:

```
arr = np.array(["one", "one", 2, 2])
result = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)[1]
print(result)
# [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

but `NaN` values included and those being ignored during indexing:

```
arr = np.array([nan, "one", 2, 2])
result = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)[1]
print(result)
# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I have already tried doing the following:

```
arr = np.array([nan, "one", 2, 2])
result = np.unique(arr[~np.isnan(arr)], return_inverse=True)[1]
print(result)
# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the
```

What I would like to get from the example above:

```
arr = np.array([nan, "one", 2, 2])
result = #...
print(result)
# [nan, 1, 0, 0]
```

Please note that `arr` is of `dtype=object` because it contains variable data types `int` and `str`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `unique` uses sorting, so can't work with the mixed objects of your array.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that makes sense. A possible workaround: if I replace the NaNs with empty strings `""` and turn the array `dtype` into `str` I can sort them. However, I would like to always have the NaNs have index 0. Do empty strings make sure they are indexed first? Any ideas?

Comment: If you care going to use `dtype=object` you might as well use a regular `list` and stay in Python-land

Comment: You're right, makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the array is string dtype:

```
In [293]: arr = np.array(["one", "one", 2, 2])
In [294]: arr
Out[294]: array(['one', 'one', '2', '2'], dtype='<U21')
In [295]: np.unique(arr)
Out[295]: array(['2', 'one'], dtype='<U21')
```

If we specify object dtype

```
In [298]: arr = np.array(["one", "one", 2, 2], object)
In [299]: arr
Out[299]: array(['one', 'one', 2, 2], dtype=object)
In [300]: np.unique(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 333, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Note the **sort** in the traceback.

What is your `nan`?

```
In [306]: arr = np.array([nan, "one", 2, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-306-abe4f4fe7b97>", line 1, in <module>
    arr = np.array([nan, "one", 2, 2])
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

In [307]: arr = np.array([np.nan, "one", 2, 2])
In [308]: arr
Out[308]: array(['nan', 'one', '2', '2'], dtype='<U32')
```

`nan` is a float:

```
In [309]: arr = np.array([np.nan, 3, 2, 2])
In [310]: arr
Out[310]: array([nan,  3.,  2.,  2.])
In [311]: np.unique(arr)
Out[311]: array([ 2.,  3., nan])
```

`unique` on floats can be tricky, since floats aren't always "equal" if

`np.unique` uses `np.lib.arraysetops._unique1d` which has some special handling for `nan` (since `nan` isn't equal to anything, not even itself).

A sample string sorting

```
In [321]: np.sort(['one','a','B','','_',' '])
Out[321]: array(['', ' ', 'B', '_', 'a', 'one'], dtype='<U3')
```

It's been some time since I looked at string sorting (ASCII characters), so can't say exactly what the order is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the problem. `dtype=object` not sortable. Is there a sortable `dtype` that contains NaNs other than `'<U32'`? I have tried `'<U32'` already but chances are my "NaN" strings do not get index 0. E.g. when having "." entries. "." is prioritized over "NaN" due to string sorting. Maybe there is also a way to mask the NaNs to be ignored during sorting?

Comment: According to https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/z1epts.htm "blank ASCII" is ranked first. But I don't know if replacing "NaN" with ""  is good programming practice. My overarching goal is to simply encode uniques inside a 2D array (or Pandas df) of different dtypes as integers. Using their indices is one approach. Now that I think of it `pd.factorize()` might be the solution.

Comment: There's a set of `np.nan...` functions, but they all depend on the dtype being float.  The `nan` are either removed, or set of to innocuous value, so it can do things like `sum` and `mean`.